# How to connect orientdb cluster with pyorient in python

Tags: orientdb

How to connect orientdb cluster with pyorient in python?
My orientdb cluster has two host in one server, the hosts ports are 2425 and 2426.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if it can be useful to you, at this [link](http://danilnagy.github.io/dmc/2015/09/16/accessing-orientdb-through-python/) there is an example of OrientDB with python use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two clients, one for each cluster.

```
client1 = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2425)
# I do not why yet, but you need to first connect as root.
session1_id = client1.connect('root',root_password) 
cluster1_info = client1.db_open(db_name, db_username, user_password)
```

Then your other client

```
client2 = pyorient.OrientDB("localhost", 2426)

session2_id = client2.connect('root',root_password) 
cluster2_info = client2.db_open(db_name, db_username, user_password)
```

Hope this will help ;)